# FIWARE Metadata in IoTAgent

Tags: monitoring, iot, fiware, lorawan

I try to set up a TTN based LoRaWAN Monitoring of my Gateways and devices inside a FIWARE-Environment. Therefore it would be essential to access data not in `payload_field` of the MQTT-Broker of TTN.

I wonder if it is possible to access field like counter, port, app_id and metadata.

[image: TTN-Frame]

I did not find a possibility yet. Does any of you face the same problem and got a solution to this challenge?

I use the following relevant FIWARE-components in a docker environment:

[fiware/orion:2.2.0](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion)

[fiware/iotagent-lorawan:1.2.3](https://github.com/FIWARE-GEs/iotagent-lorawan)

mongo:3.6.8

Answer (score 0):

If you need to receive metadata directly from LoRaWAN, you will have to customize the code within the LoRaWAN IoT Agent - this just passes *measures* by default, but the IoT Agent node lib interface is capable of receiving metadata as well.

Alternatively a recent [PR Request](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/pull/836) for the IoT Agent node lib allows for additional static metadata to be added during the provisioning stage and sent as part of the requests to the context broker. You would need to use the latest development code base as the library hasn't been ported to the LoRaWAN IoT Agent yet - amend the `iotagent-node-lib` dependency in the `package.json` as shown:

```
"dependencies": {
... 
    "iotagent-node-lib": "git://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib.git#master",
...
  },
... etc
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://iotagent-node-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-topics/index.html#metadata-support)

Attributes with `metadata` are provisioned with an additional parameter as shown:

```
"attributes": [
        {"object_id": "s", "name": "state", "type":"Text"},
        {"object_id": "l", "name": "luminosity", "type":"Integer",
          "metadata":{
              "unitCode":{"type": "Text", "value" :"CAL"}
          }
        }
```